# Is there a way to build a device without screen, buttons and USB but still able to connect to WiFi?

Tags: user-interface, network-programming, embedded, wifi, user-experience

I am sure I am not the first one thinking about this problem...

I am thinking of a prototype of a wireless smart home embedded device which is not supposed to have screen, buttons (well, apart from on/off) and USB or any other interface. But a user still needs to control it over network. How can I make it connecting to WiFi if entering a username and password is not possible?

An example of such device could be a wireless hands free sitting in a driver's ear but they connect over Bluetooth, not WiFi.

Comment: Something along the lines of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi with sealed USB?

Comment: The device cannot have USB for some reason. Can I connect to WiFi without necessity of USB and screen?

Comment: The Google Chromecast supports WiFi without a screen, buttons, or USB.  It serves its own WiFi network during configuration so that you can connect with your phone and provide the credentials for your household network.

Comment: Sounds like and Apple AirPort too, so yes it can be done.  As @kkrambo suggests, it can start in access-point mode, and switch to client mode.

Comment: what does the lack of a display, etc have to do with a lack of a login?  if you have an interface (bluetooth, ethernet/wifi, serial, etc) you can have a login if you want.   think of wireless hands free in a drivers ear but wifi not bluetooth (which has a login/password when you pair it)

Comment: yes absolutely there is a way, why wouldnt there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code it so that it has a stored wifi SSID/password (which at first start up would be empty). When the device starts up, it first checks if it has a stored SSID and if so tries to connect to that network. If it doesn't have a stored SSID or it can't connect to that network, it turns itself into a hotspot with a known (or no) password and a web server running so you can connect to it using e.g. A mobile phone/tablet/laptop and the server gives you a web page to specify the wifi SSID/password to connect to. When you click 'Set', the device stores these, then it might reboot and when it comes up this all starts again at the top - so this time it finds the wifi SSID and connects...

Comment: Most wifi connected light bulbs use this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I would say like when you have a wireless router, they first create a wifi network that you join and then you can do your configuration on there - and I suppose there should also be a method to reset your device then just in case the wifi credentials change or whatever.